# Twitter API only posting to developer linked account?

Tags: javascript, api, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-login

I have been trying to play around with Twitter API and using the `npm i twitter-lite` library. I want for others to post something through my website when they click on post and sign in, however, it only posts to my developer account. The following is my code:

```
const config = require('./config');
const twitter = require('twitter-lite');
const client = new twitter(config);



client
  .getRequestToken("website")
  .then(res =>
    console.log({
      reqTkn: res.oauth_token,
      reqTknSecret: res.oauth_token_secret
    })
  )
  .catch(console.error);


  client.post('statuses/update', { status: 'testing' }).then(result => {
    console.log('You successfully tweeted this : "' + result.text + '"');
  }).catch(console.error);
```

Appreciate any advice.

Comment: It sounds like you’ve hard-coded the access token and secret for your account taken from the developer app dashboard. To post from another account, you need to implement Sign-in with Twitter and use the tokens for the account of the user you want to post from.